# Filtering during CALCULATETABLE using values from another table (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables in a Power BI workspace:

`Table 1` is derived from a query that extracts a list of orders and the products within them.

```
CustomerID    OrderID    ProductID    Country    Date
0010234       9235064    V24-GY       UK         04/07/2018
0010234       9235064    AB5-84       UK         04/07/2018
0010234       9235064    RIM-3S       UK         04/07/2018
0010234       4812623    V79-GY       UK         27/09/2018
0049371       7924823    V24-GY       UK         09/10/2018
0049371       7924823    59H-PW       UK         09/10/2018
```

`Table 2` contains a list of unique `OrderID` values that included a certain product, `X` (e.g. `V24-GY`).  This was created using `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` and applying a `FILTER` that searched for product `X` in Table 1

```
OrderID
9235064
7924823
```

I would like to use the `OrderID` values in `Table 2` as a filter for `Table 1` so that I can create a new table, `Table 3`.

```
CustomerID    OrderID    ProductID    Country    Date
0010234       9235064    V24-GY       UK         04/07/2018
0010234       9235064    AB5-84       UK         04/07/2018
0010234       9235064    RIM-3S       UK         04/07/2018
0049371       7924823    V24-GY       UK         09/10/2018
0049371       7924823    59H-PW       UK         09/10/2018
```

I've tried to use `CALCULATETABLE` with `FILTER` but `Table 2` isn't recognized as a valid name/entity and so can't be used.

How can I get to `Table 3`?

Comment: Do you need to have `Table 2` separately or is it just an intermediate step to get `Table 3`?

Comment: @AlexisOlson - I created it as an intermediate step in my journey to create Table 3

Comment: In that case, it's may not be best to create it as it's own calculated table. Can you outline what you intend the end result `Table 3` to look like? It's possible you can skip the intermediate step altogether.

Comment: Thanks @AlexisOlson.  What I want to get is a table that shows me  the contents of all orders where at least 1 of product X was purchased.  In a way it's a type of affinity matrix (I've been looking at market basket techniques too).

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure you don't need an intermediate table, but it's quite difficult to say for sure since you haven't shown any example tables. A [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful in answering this.

Comment: Let me know if this helps @AlexisOlson and if I can provide additional details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this where you only calculate `Table2` as a variable instead of a calculated table that shows up in your data model.

`Table3` can be calculated as follows:

```
 Table3 = 
     VAR Table2 = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Table1[OrderID],
                      FILTER(Table1, Table1[ProductID] = "V24-GY"))
     RETURN FILTER(Table1, Table1[OrderID] IN Table2)
```

---

Here's a similar method that skips the summarizing.

```
Table3 = FILTER(Table1,
             Table1[OrderID] IN
                 SELECTCOLUMNS(
                     FILTER(Table1, Table1[ProductID] = "V24-GY"),
                     "OrderID", Table1[OrderID]))
```

Comment: **Quick note in case this impacts others.**  When I ran the above I kept on getting an error stating that there was a duplicate value that wasn't permitted for columns on one side of a many-to-one relationship.  Check your relationships (Home -> Manage Relationships) as sometimes joins are created which should not be there.